# Alpha number Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Some what confused on a regex to validate an alpha-numeric field of the following format:

XX77777 (Max characters must be 7)

First two characters must be alpha ( A-Z)

Comment: [*what have you tried?*](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Are first two chars only upper case or upper and lower case?

Comment: Also, what are the minimum number of characters the field can have? Is it case sensitive?

Comment: sorry folks, I forgot to post my tried solution. Apologies

Comment: @user918171 In that case you can edit your question and add the information.

Comment: Before we close this one, OP should have the chance to improve his or her question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
[A-Z]{2}\d{0,5}
```

I wonder where your confusion might come from. This one is pretty basic, you should go thru a regex reference (like [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)), it will take you 10 minutes.